# How to decrypt TLS1.3 packets in scapy with session keys or handshake/traffic secrets

Tags: python, scapy, tls1.3

I'm analysing TLS1.3 traffic using wireshark. Using a keylog I am able to decrypt the traffic there. I was wondering if it is possible to decrypt the packet in scapy as well. I have seen that there is a TLS layer available in scapy but I'm not sure how I can inject the additional information that scapy needs (session keys or shared secrets) to decrypt the traffic that I read from a pcap file.